# I'm getting an IntegrityError at /post/new/ NOT NULL constraint failed: blog_post.author_id

Tags: python, django

Im trying to remove the dropdown so that the user can only see his/her username.[Image of the author dropdown](https://github.com/K3v1n0153/IntegrityError-at-post-new-NOT-NULL-constraint-failed-blog_post.author_id.git).[image that i want to happen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCK3F.png)

[The code](https://github.com/K3v1n0153/IntegrityError-at-post-new-NOT-NULL-constraint-failed-blog_post.author_id.git)

Comment: Please include the relevant code parts in the question, such that the question is more self-contained.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the `author` of the `Post` if you create a new one:

```
class CreatePostView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post 
    form_class = PostForm
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'blog/post_detail.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```